# Storing animated GIFs on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My own tests have shown that GIF images saved to the Windows Phone 8 MediaLibrary always get converted to JPG. Is there any way around that other than managing my own library - which I'm already doing?

Comment: how do you save gif images ?

Comment: Since even animated GIFs saved by Internet Explorer are converted to JPG, I'm afraid it's not possible. At least, I searched a long time for my own app and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic Well, either by long-pressing them in IE or programatically.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can not directly save .gif file into Media Library, you can try to save in Camera Roll using [Image Tool](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) Library.

Hope it helps

Comment: No image library in the world can solve the problem of WP converting GIFs to JPG when saved to the media library.

Comment: Alright, I thing you can directly save in app isolated storage.

Comment: Of course I can. But Isolated Storage is not the media library, right?

Comment: Yes! You are right. I don't know what is your requirement for your application; just a suggestion *if* your application want to show all media library images in your application then you can go for this approach... while fetching images from the Media Library through your windows phone application you can also fetch the images from your application Isolated Storage too.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear up some misconceptions here, WP8 does in fact save gifs from IE, MMS, emails etc as full gif files, NOT jpgs. It is just that when displayed in the Picture hub, only the first frame is displayed. WP7, however, did convert gif to jpg on save.

You can prove this yourself by downloading the [GIF Viewer app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/gif-viewer/d2e3a376-b548-446f-8fb0-2d96eded30e6) which will allow you to browse and play gifs in your media library.